# Kendo Window jumps on drag and resize

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have a page that loads a KendoUI Window, and everything really seems to work fine for what I am currently doing.

But, one thing I have noticed is that when I grab the widget to resize or drag it, it jumps position about 20px, which is messing up some of the placement constraints I am trying to enforce.

Does anyone else experience this 'jump'? and if so is there someone I can prevent it?

[image]

So above is a 2 state image, and all I did here was grab the header to drag, moved a pixel or two to start the drag, and then it jumped another 'x' pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer! Turns out kendoWindow does not approve of the body tag having a border applied, which is a default in basically any of the MVC 4 project templates.

Removing the  'border-top: solid 10px #000' from Site.css fixes the issue.